# JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112)

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp

i have tried to build the maven project.it was build successfully and raise the 
 JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112): on getting class status
 [util.c:1285] in console

Answer (score 0):

I also just experienced this issue. I do not have a solution, but I will add that this was after my application had been open on the desktop since the day before.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This does not seem to provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)